# DelayedJob ion Rails 3: Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm building a Rails 3 app that uses [**delayed_job**](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) to schedule asynchronous tasks in the background.

It works fine when I use the `.delay` method or `.handle_asynchronously` to queue a job, but when I use  a custom job it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

In my lib folder I have the Ruby class with the perform method in a file called `my_job.rb` that contains:

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(:text)
  def perform
    puts text
  end
end
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue MyJob.new('test')
```

When I call the controller I get the following error:

```
Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Delayed::Job
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed delayed_job properly; https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#installation (notice that the gem is now called gem 'delayed_job_active_record' if you're using ActiveRecord as backend)

Upgrade instructions here from delayed_job 2.x to 3.0: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#upgrading-from-2x-to-300-on-active-record